# How to handle complex static data in Django 1.7

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have a django app that is deployed on three environments in the standard production-staging-development style.The app has several models with fields that will essentially be just choices. I have coded these using the format:

```
CHOICE1 = 1
CHOICE2 = 2

CHOICES = ((CHOICE1, 'Choice 1'),
            (CHOICE2, 'Choice 2'),)

choice = IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

This was OK and allowed me to do nice things like `something==CHOICE1` rather than `something==1` . However, now I want to make the data more complex by having fields in which multiple choices can be made (many to many) and potentially other data about choices (e.g. whether or not they are to be displayed) all of which would be pretty much static (might have to change slightly as the app evolves).

All of this points towards storing it in the database, except the fact that its static data. The other problem with storing it in the database, is keeping the data consistent across all my environments. I had thought that `inital_data` fixtures would be ideal for this but they've now been deprecated in 1.7. The recommended alternative is to use data migrations but from what I can tell this is non-trivial and would require a migration for every change to the data rather than having one file which reflects the state of the static data in its entirety. Is this correct?

What I want is to be able to have:

- One file in which the static data is stored,
- That data to be pushed to the database automatically, say on every migrate (can override the
  DB data)
- A way to reference a choice using constant defined in code

Is this possible?